# Bind javascript method in Angularjs template

Tags: angularjs

My application is using Angularjs at client side. I have five directive which are using same logic. Following are required details of my code

1. I have one pure javascript class as AppUtilities.js having following method defined

   ```
   var AppUtilities = {
     //Get the guid for given collection
     getGUID: function (collectionName) {
         var prefix;
         var guid;
         //get first two character
         if (!Utilities.isEmpty(collectionName)) {
            prefix = collectionName.substring(0, 2);
            //Get timestamp
            var timestamp = Utilities.getTimestampId();
            //concate prefix to get the guid
            guid = prefix + timestamp;
         }
         return guid;
     }
   };
   ```
2. I have five different directive in which I need to use "getGUID()" method to bind with template. Since template is only able to bind with scope function therefore I have defined scope method in all these five template as below

   ```
   scope.getGUID = function (collectionName) {
     return AppUtilities.getGUID(collectionName);
   }
   ```
3. Then in all the five directive template, this method is bind as scope variable

   ```
   <h4 class="guid" id="guid" data-ng-bind-template="{{getGUID('goal')}}"></h4>
   ```

How can I avoid declaring these method as scope variable and directly use as `AppUtilities.getGUID(collectionName)` in the HTML template?

Comment: put AppUtilities in rootScope

Comment: With [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), which are usable in all templates once defined, you could use `{{ 'goal'|getGUID }}`. No scope vars, no manipulation of `$rootScope`.

Comment: create a service and put this method inside a service..then you need to do  `$scope.AppUtilities = AppUtilities` to make it available in `scope/html`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways, but honestly, it seems like more effort than its worth, since you can just do:

```
scope.getGUID = AppUtilities.getGUID;
```

Of course, you *could* use `$rootScope`, but to me personally it feels wrong - I like when things are explicitly declared and do not magically appear.

Alternatively, if you only need to render the GUID in the UI, create a `GUID` directive. For example:

```
.directive("guid", function(){
  return {
    template: "<span>{{getGUID()}}</span>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       scope.getGUID = function(){
         return AppUtilities.getGUID(attrs.guid || attrs.name);
       };
    }
  }
});
```

and use as:

```
<h4 class="guid"><guid name="goal"></guid></h4>
```

Comment: your solution is cool..still thinking creating service would be an better option too..

Comment: @pankajparkar, well, that's what I suggested as well as a first option

Comment: Great..That perfect one +1.. I also suggested the same in comments

Comment: Yeah, I saw... but I wanted to give the OP another potential option

Answer (score 2):

Without manipulating the individual scopes or the root scope, you could simply define a filter which is usable in all templates. Note that, for all the good reasons, I'd still define and inject `AppUtilities`, even if it is a global, as it's own service.

```
app.filter('toGUID', ['AppUtilities', function (AppUtilities) {
  return function (input) {
    return AppUtilities.getGUID(input);
  };
}]);

// <pre>{{ 'goal'|toGUID }}</pre>

app.service('AppUtilities', function () {
  return AppUtilities;
});
```

```js
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.filter('toGUID', ['AppUtilities', function (AppUtilities) {
    return function (input) {
      return AppUtilities.getGUID(input);
    };
  }]);
  
  app.service('AppUtilities', function () {
    return AppUtilities;
  });

  var Utilities = {
    isEmpty: function (collectionName) {
      return false;
    },
    getTimestampId: function () {
      return '_something';
    }
  };

  var AppUtilities = {
    //Get the guid for given collection
    getGUID: function (collectionName) {
      var prefix;
      var guid;
      //get first two character
      if (!Utilities.isEmpty(collectionName)) {
        prefix = collectionName.substring(0, 2);
        //Get timestamp
        var timestamp = Utilities.getTimestampId();
        //concat prefix to get the guid
        guid = prefix + timestamp;
      }
      return guid;
    }
  };

})(angular.module('app', []), angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
  <pre>{{ 'goal'|toGUID }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it in a div:

```
<div id="hidden" data-ng-model="hidden" style="display:none"></div>
<script>
$('#hidden').html(AppUtilities.getGUID(collectionName));
</script>
```

Then, ng-bind to the div's contents:

```
<div id="realDiv" data-ng-bind-html="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: i think it's not a good solution according to angularjs way of doing thinks ( avoid the use of jquery as possible )

Comment: the question specifically states "avoid declaring these method as scope variable". everyone else here was like, uh nope. i'm simply answering the question.